# Consulta mysql com subquery em NodeJs

Tags: javascript, mysql, array, node.js

Tenho a seguinte estrutura nas seguintes tabelas.

parceiro (idParceiro, nome, email, telefone) exemplo
parceiroTag (idParceiro, tag)

O que eu preciso fazer, um select na tabela parceiro e fazer um for no resultado e consultar a tabela parceiroTag pelo idParceiro e trazer os resultados para preencher um Json que fique dessa forma.

```js
[{
  nome: 'nome teste',
  email: 'email teste',
  telefone: 1199999999,
  tags: ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3']
}, {
  nome: 'nome teste',
  email: 'email teste',
  telefone: 1199999999,
  tags: ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3']
}]
```

O problema é que quando eu consulto a primeira tabela e faço um for no resultado para pegar o ID e ir na outra tabela ele se perde por ser async.

Como posso resolver isso no NODE.JS pois tenho varias consultas que dependem de outra para gerar um Json.

Segue abaixo meu código.

```js
router.route('/parceiro').get(function(req, res) {
  parceiro.consultar(req, function(err, rows){
    if(err) return res.status(400).json(err);

    var p  = [];
    _.each(rows, function(one) {
      var pa = {};
      pa.parceiroId = one.parceiroId;
      pa.clienteId = one.clienteId;
      pa.nome = one.nome;
      pa.imagemDestaque = one.imagemDestaque;
      pa.imagemLogo = one.imagemLogo;
      pa.desconto = one.desconto;
      pa.titulo = one.titulo;
      pa.descricao = one.descricao;
      pa.urlSite = one.urlSite;
      pa.validadeDe = one.validadeDe;
      pa.validadeAte = one.validadeAte;
      pa.isCupom = one.isCupom;
      pa.urlOferta = one.urlOferta;
      pa.cupomDesconto = one.cupomDesconto;
      pa.ativo = one.ativo;
      pa.dataCadastro = one.dataCadastro;
      pa.tags = [];
      parceiro.tag(req, function(err, r){
        _.each(r, function(two) {
          pa.tags.push(two.tag);
        });
      });
      pa.categorias = [];
      pa.regioes = [];
      p.push(pa);
    });
    return res.status(200).json(p);
  });
});
```

Comment: Coloca por favor o código em texto e não imagem. A lógica de `res.status` deve estar dentro de `parceiro.tag()`, e aí espera por essa resposta/callback. Mas não podias fazer isso num só SELECT com um JOIN?

Comment: Não da em um só select porque tenho um parceiro pode ter 100 tags e categorias e regiões ainda que vão ser no formado {idRegiao:1, nome:'nome da regiao'}.

Comment: Não seria mais limpo `var pa = one;`? em vez de estar a passar as propriedades uma a uma?

Comment: one é da tabela parceiro que não tem as propriedades tags, categorias e regiões, só se puderem ser inclusas depois.

Comment: Ok, e queres o mesmo para as regioes, e categorias como `parceiro.tag`?

Comment: Sim eu tenho aquele for e dentro dele quero consultar as 3 tabelas separadamente, o problema é só que quando ele entra no método parceiro.tag() o valor fica la dentro e não consigo jogar para o pa.tags.push().

Comment: Eu percebo o problema e vejo o erro. Pergunto para acertar melhor na resposta.

Comment: A tabela chama-se `tag` ou `tags`? tens a propriedade como `tags` mas a tabela `tag`? e as outras?

Comment: Deixei uma resposta, aqui é hora de dormir. Dou uma olhada amanhã a ver se conseguiste compreender a logica e se te ajudou. (Ou se encontras-.te algum bug :P )

Answer (score 1):

Uma outra abordagem, ainda melhor que fazer isso no Node.js é fazer essa junção de dados no MySQL.

Assim podes concatenar as tags com o `GROUP_CONCAT` e receber isso nas colunas das `row` que o MySQL retorna, sem teres de fazer várias queries para ir buscar "pedaços" da informação.

Testa assim:

```
SELECT p.id, p.nome, GROUP_CONCAT(t.tag) AS tags FROM parceiro AS p
INNER JOIN parceiroTag AS t ON p.id = t.parceiroid
GROUP BY id
```

#### Exemplo [aqui (link).](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/10a9fd/3)

Answer (score 0):

Precisas encadear essa lógica para só chamares o `res.status().json()` quando esse objeto tiver todas as propriedades que precisas. E como tudo é assícrono a coisa complica um pouco.

Um biblioteca boa para trabalhar esses encadeamentos, [chama-se `async`](https://github.com/caolan/async#composefn1-fn2). Mas fazendo "à mão" acho que precisas de algo assim:

```
function waitForIt(obj, tables, done) {
    var callbacks = 0;
    return function(err) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        callbacks++;
        if (callbacks == tables.length) done(err, obj);
    }
}

function join(table, obj, cb) {
    parceiro[table](req, function(err, r) {
        obj[table] = r.map(function(row) {
            return row.tag;
        });
        cb(err);
    });
}

router.route('/parceiro').get(function(req, res) {
    parceiro.consultar(req, function(err, rows) {
        if (err) return res.status(400).json(err);
        rows.forEach(function(pa) {
            var cb = waitForIt(pa, ['tag', 'regi'], function(err, obj) {
                if (err) return res.status(400).json(err);
                return res.status(200).json(obj);
            });
            tables.forEach(function(table) {
                join(table, pa, cb);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

A ideia é chamar as tabelas todas que precisas, juntar ao objeto o que a tabela traz e depois, só quando todas as callbacks das subqueries tiverem sido chamadas; só então chamar a ultima callback a que dei nome de `done`.

**Notas:**

- #1 fiz o código agora, não testei, mas é éssa a lógica que precisas.
- #2 ainda acho que dava para fazer isso só com MySQL :)
- #3 usar `if (err) return res.status(400).json(err);` vai expôr ao utilizador erros internos da aplicação e pode gerar falhas na segurança da BD.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui fazer da seguinte forma.

```js
exports.consultar  = function (req, callback) {
  req.getConnection(function(err,connection){
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM parceiro', function(err, result){
      done = _.after(result.length, function () {
        callback(err, result)
      });
      result.forEach(function(pa){
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM parceiroTag where parceiroId = ' + pa.parceiroId, function(err, result){
          pa.tags = [];
          for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            pa.tags.push(result[i].tag);
          }
          done();
        });
      });
    });
  });
};
```

Obrigado pela ajuda de todos.

Comment: Deves escolher uma resposta correta.

Comment: Esta resposta usa a mesma lógica que eu sugeri, via `_.after` do underscore. Vou juntar uma resposta só com MySQL