# passar variáveis para view EJS de consultas distintas

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js

estou começando com node/express etc.
Crie um site com a intenção de aprendizando e estou precisando de ajuda.

Tenho uma query em mysql que é enviada para uma view EJS via o código abaixo:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  connection.query('SELECT actor_id, first_name, last_name, last_update FROM actor',
     function (error, results, fields) {
      res.render('index', { title: 'Render by app.get',
        datasetresult  : results
      });
    });
});
```

Uso essa variável para fazer o data binding com uma tabela (SAPIU5 componente)

Quero na mesma pagina, ou seja, index usar uma outra variável para preencher outra tabela.
Estou usando a mesma lógica, mas não está funcionando

```
var Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;
var client = new Client();
client.get("http://api.randomuser.me/",
  function (data, response) {
    data = JSON.stringify(data.results),
       res.render('index', {
         datasetapi : data
       });
    });
});
```

Se eu usar um dos dois funciona os dois ao mesmo tempo não funciona.

Eu já tentei de algumas formas resolver esse problema, mas não consegui.

Observação, por está usando componentes especificos na view EJS (estou usando SAPUI5) preciso ter o resultado em duas variáveis, pois desta forma posso fazer o databind para os componentes (tabelas).
Nesse momento só tem uma tabela, não consegui ter as duas variaveis com dados.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge' />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>

    <script id='sap-ui-bootstrap'
      <script src='https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js'
      data-sap-ui-theme='sap_goldreflection'
      data-sap-ui-libs='sap.ui.commons, sap.ui.table'>
    </script>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-cCueBR6CsyA4/9szpPfrX3s49M9vUU5BgtiJj06wt/s="
            crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>

    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    var oMysql = <%-JSON.stringify(datasetresult)%>;

    var oApi   = <%-JSON.stringify(datasetapi)

    var oTable = new sap.ui.table.Table({
             width: "1000px",
             visibleRowCount: 10
         });
         oTable.setTitle("Actor Details");

         oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
             label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({ text: "Id" }),
             template: new sap.ui.commons.TextView().bindProperty("text", "actor_id"),
               width: "70px"
         }));

         oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
             label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({ text: "First Name" }),
             template: new sap.ui.commons.TextView().bindProperty("text", "first_name"),
             sortProperty: "first_name",
               //filterProperty: "lastName",
               width: "230px"
         }));

         oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
             label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({ text: "Last Name" }),
             template: new sap.ui.commons.TextView().bindProperty("text", "last_name"),
             width: "230px"
         }));

         //Create a model and bind the table rows to this model
         var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
         oModel.setData({modelData: oMysql});
         oTable.setModel(oModel);
         oTable.bindRows("/modelData");
         oTable.placeAt("content");
    </script>
  </head>


  <body class="sapUiBody" role="application">
   <div id="content"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Como eu faço para gerar uma variável da consulta sql é usa-la na view juntamente com uma outra variável de uma consulta API.

Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tens de encadear esses dois métodos assíncronos para só chamares o `.render` quando tiveres ambas as respostas. Podes fazer isso de maneiras diferentes.

Já falei sobre isso noutras respostas, sugeri [com Promises](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/137828/129), com [o módulo async](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/130068/129) ou com [gestor feito á mão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/123494/129).

No teu caso como são só duas callbacks podes fazer assim:

```
var Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;
var client = new Client();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    client.get("http://api.randomuser.me/", function(data, response) {
        connection.query('SELECT actor_id, first_name, last_name', function(error, results, fields) {
            res.render('index', {
                title: 'Render by app.get',
                datasetresult: results,
                datasetapi: JSON.stringify(data.results)
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Sergio, muitissimo obrigado. Vc não tem ideia de como eu já pesquisei, já estudei callback, closure etc, pra tentar conseguir fazer isso. Ainda falta alguma coisa pra essa ideia de callback entrar na minha mente. rsrs.
Vou continuar estudando a teoria. 
Novamente muito obrigado. Realmente muito obrigado, vc não tem ideia o quanto eu tentei antes de postar. Valeuuuuu :)

Comment: @DouglasCorrea ótimo! Fico contente de ajudar :) Se quiseres podes marcar a resposta como aceite.

Comment: @ Sergio,

Me ajudou e ajudou muito, perdi varias horas pesquisando antes de postar aqui. 

Sobre marcar a respota com o aceite, nem sabia disso.Sou novo aqui. 
Mas já foi marcada. Novamente meu muito obrigado.  ;)

Comment: @DouglasCorrea ótimo. Se quiseres perceber melhor dei uma resposta ainda mais abrangente aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/140883/129